# While loop .isdigit. Why error for function '123' but not 'abc123'?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is this does function 1 execute but function 2 return error? (Python 3.4)

Function 1:

```
secret('abc123')
```

Function 2:

```
secret('123')
```

Code:

```
def secret(s):
i = 0
result = ''

while s[i].isdigit():
    result = result + s[i]
    i = i + 1

return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the error message you're getting, but my guess would be because you aren't checking `i` to make sure it isn't going past the length of the string. The first example works because the first character is not a digit, thus breaking your loop before it can extend past the bounds. Change your `while` to this:

```
while i<len(s) and s[i].isdigit():
```

This will make sure `i` doesn't skip past the bounds of your string length.